# Recharts Breaking on unrelated State change (Re-render)

Tags: reactjs, frontend, recharts

I am using a simple bar graph from Recharts, which works perfectly when the page loads.

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
          <BarChart
            width={500}
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
              top: 5,
              right: 30,
              left: 20,
              bottom: 5,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="country" />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip itemStyle={{ color: '#000000' }} />
            <Legend />
            <Bar dataKey="value" fill="#8884d8" />
          </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

I have a state variable called `age` within the same component, which is unrelated to the bar graph, but somehow when the state changes (on re-render), say on a button click, the entire graph breaks and turns blank.

[image]

After clicking the button:

[image]

Onclick code:

```
<button onClick={() => setAge(1)}>click</button>
```

Comment: So where is the offending `onClick` handler code? We need to see the code creating the issue - no the _perfect_ code.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Added it, have a look. thanks.

Comment: Something is obliterating the `data` prop. Please create a [example]